# Make a list scroll to bottom with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list and when I insert an item, i want to the list to scroll to the bottom automatically when my `@ObservedObject` changed.

There is my actual View code :

```
struct DialogView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = DialogViewModel()

    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(self.viewModel.discussion, id: \.uuid) {
                    Text($0.content)
                }
            }.animation(Animation.easeOut)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Now with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 it can be solved using `ScrollViewReader/ScrollViewProxy` in `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack` (for performance, rows reuse, etc) as follows

```
struct DialogView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = DialogViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { sp in
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(self.viewModel.discussion, id: \.uuid) {
                        Text($0.content).id($0.uuid)
                    }
                }
                .onReceive(viewModel.$discussion) { _ in
                    guard !viewModel.discussion.isEmpty else { return }

                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut) {
                        sp.scrollTo(viewModel.discussion.last!.uuid)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Asperi, do you if it's possible to do this with a regular array instead of an array wrapped in an `ObservableObject`? My view just gets an array injected in its initializer and so that regular array does not conform to Publisher. I tried defining it with @Binding, but that doesn't seem to help.