# SwiftUI Scroll automatically with duration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to implement a ScrollView that scrolls visible automatically to the end of an array. There are some examples in the AppStore where content starts scrolling automatically and you can see it slowly.
With this code below it will automatically scroll to the last item without seeing it. How can I add a duration or animation to it that I can see it scrolling?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    ScrollViewReader {
        scrollView in
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(self.drinkNames, id: \.self) {
                    drink in
                        ShowContent(drink: drink)
                        .padding(.leading)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                scrollView.scrollTo(drinkNames[drinkNames.endIndex - 1])
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will using an animation block work? Not sure whether it's possible in swiftUI

Comment: Does this work?       withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
    scrollView.scrollTo(drinkNames[drinkNames.endIndex - 1])
            
}

Comment: @TibinThomas thanks's for your answer but there is still the same problem as described.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683038/12299030?

Comment: No because it will do the same as my code. I want a slow visible scrolling effect like in some cards of the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an animation, like this:

```
.onAppear {
    withAnimation {
        scrollView.scrollTo(drinkNames[drinkNames.endIndex - 1])
    }
}
```